# Dask DataFrame.to_parquet fails on read - repartition - write operation

Tags: python, pandas, dask, parquet, dask-distributed

I have the following workflow.

```
def read_file(path, indx):
    df = pd.read_parquet(path)
    df.index = [indx] * len(df)
    return df

files_list = get_all_files()  # list of 10k parquet files, each about 1MB
df = dask.dataframe.from_delayed([dask.delayed(read_file)(x, indx) for (indx, x) in enumerate(files_list)])
df.divisions = list(range(10000)) + [9999] # each divisions include 1 file
new_divisions = [0, 10, 23, 45, ...., 9999] # new_divisions that reduces number of partitions by putting a bunch of files into same partitions. 
df = df.repartition(divisions = new_divisions)
df.to_parquet("fewer_files") # This causes dask to essentially freeze and no files get written
```

The new divisions are chosen so that the total memory of the files in each partition doesn't exceed 1000 MB. However, the final to_parquet call hangs forever. On the dask dashboard, there is no activity. The memory consumed by all workers remains very small (55MB), at least in the dashboard; but I suspect it might just be not updating since everything becomes super slow. The python process running the code keeps increasing the memory consumption (the virtual memory in Mac keeps increasing; I let it go upto 30GB).

If there are only about 200 files in the files_list, the code works just fine. Here is what the df.visualize() looks like when there are 236 files in files_list which gets repartitioned into 41 partitions:
[image: Task graph for df]

Any idea on what might be causing the df.to_parquet to freeze when there are 10k files? When I print df before computation it shows the following:

> npartitions=65, Dask Name: repartition-merge, 26417 tasks

Also, I can get the *df.get_partition(0).to_parquet*  or other partition to work fairly quickly. However, *df.to_parquet* on the whole dataset fails.  Is the 26K tasks simply too much to handle for 4 workers in my laptop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`dask.dataframe.read_parquet`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.read_parquet.html) or other dask I/O implementations, not `dask.delayed` wrapping pandas I/O operations, whenever possible. Giving dask direct access to the file object or filepath allows the scheduler to quickly assess the steps in the job and accurately estimate the job size & requirements without executing the full workflow.

#### Explanation

By using dask.delayed with the pandas read_parquet reader, you're essentially robbing dask of the ability to peek into the file structure in order to help schedule the job, and also to open and close the files multiple times when running the full job (a problem you haven't even gotten to yet).

When everything fits neatly into memory, using `dask.dataframe.read_parquet` and the delayed method you use are very similar. The difference comes when the optimal strategy is not simply "read in all the data and then figure out what to do with it". Specifically, you are performing many reindexing and sorting operations, all of which require dask to know a lot about the contents of the files before the index-manipulation operations can even be scheduled.

Essentially, wrapping something in `dask.delayed` tells dask "here's this unknown block of code. Run it as a pure-python black box lots of times. The `dask.dataframe` and `dask.array` interfaces have smaller APIs and less interoperability compared with their pandas and numpy counterparts, but what you get for this is dask actually knows what's going on under the hood and can optimize it for you. When you use dask.delayed, you're gaining flexibility *at the expense of dask's ability to tune the operation for you*.

## Example

As an exmaple, I'll create a large number of tiny files:

```py
In [9]: tinydf = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [11, 21], "col2": [12, 22]})
   ...: for i in range(1000):
   ...:     tinydf.to_parquet(f"myfile_{i}.parquet")
```

***dask.dataframe.read_parquet***

Now, let's read this in with [`dask.dataframe.read_parquet`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.read_parquet.html):

```py
In [10]: df = dask.dataframe.read_parquet([f"myfile_{i}.parquet" for i in range(1000)])
```

Note that this is lightning fast. We can take a peek at the high-level task graph by inspecting the `dask` attribute:

```py
In [13]: df.dask
Out[13]:
HighLevelGraph with 1 layers.
<dask.highlevelgraph.HighLevelGraph object at 0x15f79e2f0>
 0. read-parquet-e38709bfe39c7f8dfb5c4abf2fd08b50
```

Note that dask.dataframe.read_parquet is a single concept to dask. It can tune and optimize however it needs within this task. That includes "peeking" at the files to understand their column structure, look at the metadata file/attributes, etc., without reading in all the data.

```
In [30]: df.divisions = list(range(0, 2001, 2))

In [31]: df = df.repartition(divisions=list(range(0, 2001, 500)))

In [33]: df.dask
Out[33]:
HighLevelGraph with 2 layers.
<dask.highlevelgraph.HighLevelGraph object at 0x168b5fcd0>
 0. read-parquet-e38709bfe39c7f8dfb5c4abf2fd08b50
 1. repartition-merge-bc42fb2f09234f7656901995bf3b29fa
```

The high level graph for the full workflow has two steps! Dask understands the operation in terms of file I/O and repartitions. It can decide how to split up these tasks in order to stay within memory limits and spread workload across workers, all without bogging down the scheduler.

***dask.delayed(pd.read_parquet)***

On the other hand, what happens if we do this with dask.delayed?

```py
In [14]: def read_file(path, indx):
    ...:     df = pd.read_parquet(path)
    ...:     df.index = [indx] * len(df)
    ...:     return df
    ...:
    ...:
    ...: files_list = [f"myfile_{i}.parquet" for i in range(1000)]
    ...: df = dask.dataframe.from_delayed(
    ...:     [dask.delayed(read_file)(x, indx) for (indx, x) in enumerate(files_list)]
    ...: )
```

The dataframe preview ends up looking similar, but if we peek under the hood at the high level task graph, we can see that dask needs to read in all of the data before it even knows what the index looks like!

```py
In [16]: df.dask
Out[16]:
HighLevelGraph with 1001 layers.
<dask.highlevelgraph.HighLevelGraph object at 0x168bf6230>
 0. read_file-b7aed020-1dc7-4872-a37d-d514b407a7d8
 1. read_file-a0462606-999b-4af1-9977-acb562edab67
 2. read_file-286df439-df34-4a5a-baf9-75dd0a5ae09b
 3. read_file-4db8c178-a67e-4775-b117-228ac607f02f
 4. read_file-a19d6144-5560-4da7-a1f5-8dc92b3ccf1c
 
 # yeah... really there are 1000 of these...

 998. read_file-d0cbd4a4-c255-4a77-a905-199bc289a0b5
 999. read_file-45a80080-426a-48fd-8dcb-9ba7565307f1
 1000. from-delayed-833eff6e232da1e10ca7221b961c21c1
```

To make matters worse, each `pd.read_parquet` uses the default pandas read behavior, which is to assume the data can fit into memory and just read the whole file in at once. Pandas does NOT return a file object - it loads all the data and returns a DataFrame before dask even sees it.

Because of this, dask is essentially prevented from getting to the scheduling bit until all of the read has already been done, and it has very little to work with in terms of workload balancing, memory management, etc. It can try to get a sneak-peek at the workload by executing the first task, but this is still a read of the whole first file.

This only gets worse when we start trying to shuffle the index. I won't go into it here, but you get the idea...

Comment: Brilliant. It seems obvious now that you have explained it (that delayed would mask lower level details for dask and prevent it from optimizing), but it somehow escaped my mind to try using dataframe.read_parquet instead of using delayed objects. It also explains excessive memory consumption on the calling process before even anything begins to happen. I am excited to retry with this fix and will report back!

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not able to use read_parquet directly on the list of files because the files have a different set of columns (and read_file function adds missing columns with nan currently). Any tips on how to prevent dask from having to read all the files before starting to schedule?

Comment: check out the [`dask.dataframe.read_parquet`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.read_parquet.html#dask-dataframe-read-parquet) docs - there's a `columns` argument that should help, both with ordering and subsetting the columns. And NaNs aren't *that* big an issue - you can always use additional cleaning steps like dropna or fillna later. In my defense, you weren't handling this in your original question either - the job was just failing before you encountered the problem :)

Comment: The columns argument wouldn't allow me to pass columns that are missing in some of the files (i.e. columns argument is designed to be subset; what I need is superset). You are right though, this is beyond the scope of original question and I should probably ask a new one.  This nevertheless gives me a direction of attack. Thanks!

Comment: hmm - yeah if the files aren't formatted the same way you're in for a tougher task. you could attack this as a two-step data job: (1) align & clean the individual files with delayed or client.map, then (2) read/analyze/rechunk/write the entire dataset with ddf.read_parquet.

Comment: I asked a new question specifically about this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71549122/how-to-read-list-of-parquets-with-partially-overlapping-set-of-columns-in-dask

Comment: this seems relevant: [dask/dask#8289](//github.com/dask/dask/issues/8289) - it seems that part of the issue may be related to the number of delayed tasks. You might have some luck just partitioning your list of delayed() tasks with dask.bag, essentially forcing dask to execute large groups of parquet read operations within the same process, and easing the burden on the scheduler. Unfortunately, yeah, dask.dataframe.read_* is not built to handle variable column specs: see [dask/dask#2752](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/2752).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243122/discussion-between-rajendra-and-michael-delgado).

Answer (score 1):

> The new divisions are chosen so that the total memory of the files in each partition doesn't exceed 1000 MB.

If the main consideration for repartitioning is memory, it might be a good idea to use `.repartition(partition_size='1000MB')`. The script looks like:

```py
df = dask.dataframe.from_delayed([dask.delayed(read_file)(x, indx) for (indx, x) in enumerate(files_list)])
df = df.repartition(partition_size='1000MB')
df.to_parquet("fewer_files")
```

Comment: The main objective is to combine the parquet files to reduce the number of files. However, when files are combined together, I would like to do that based on come criteria - hence the custom divisions.

Answer (score 1):

When Dask reads a Parquet file, it opens the file and might attempt to read one partition in memory to infer the data types the file contains. This depends on the engine used (`pyarrow` or `fastparquet`) and on if there's a `_metadata` file present). Both opening a file and inferring memory types are slow operations.

I suspect that is the reason why you can run your computation on 200 files, while it stalls on 10k files.

A good practice is to think about how you'll want to read your data when you're writing it.

For your specific case I'd recommend reading in the parquet data 200 files at a time, and then write your to a much smaller number of parquet files when you have it all in memory. typically a number of files equal to the number of workers you have available is sensible, assuming data from a single file fits in worker memory.

Asking your OS for 10.000 file handles may also be causing some unexpected behaviour, and could also be a cause.

Running this command on my mac system tells me my OS is limiting me to 256 open file descriptors by default:

```
launchctl limit maxfiles

maxfiles    256            unlimited
```