# How to read list of parquets with partially overlapping set of columns in dask?

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

Consider this code:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np
df1=pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [11, 12]})
df1.to_parquet("df1.parquet")
df2=pd.DataFrame({'A': [3, 4], 'C': [13, 14]})
df2.to_parquet("df2.parquet")
all_files =  ["df1.parquet", "df2.parquet"]
full_df = dd.read_parquet(all_files)

# dask.compute(full_df) # KeyError: "['B'] not in index" 
def normalize(df):
    df_cols = set(df.columns)
    for c in ['A', 'B', 'C']:
        if c not in df_cols:
            df[c] = np.nan
    df = df[sorted(df.columns)]
    return df

normal_df = full_df.map_partitions(normalize)

dask.compute(normal_df)  # Still gives keyError
```

I was hoping that after the normalization using map_partitions, I wouldn't get keyError, but the read_parquet probably fails before reaching the map_partitions step.

I could have created the DataFrame from a list of delayed objects which would each read one file and normalize the columns, but I want to avoid using delayed objects [for this reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71531717/2105924)

The other option is suggested by SultanOrazbayev is to use dask dataframe like this:

```
def normal_ddf(path):
    df = dd.read_parquet(path)
    return normalize(df) # normalize f should work with both pandas and dask

full_df = dd.concat([normal_ddf(path) for path in all_files])
```

Problem with this is that, when all_files contains large number of files (10K) this takes a long time to create the dataframe since all those dd.read_parquet happens sequentially. Although dd.read_parquet doesn't need to load the whole file, it still needs to read some headers to get column info. Doing it sequentially on 10k files adds up.

So, what is the proper/efficient way to read a bunch of parquet files all of which don't have the same set of columns?

Comment: I think you have the two options correct - read consistently formatted data with dask.dataframe.read_parquet or preprocess the data with dask.delayed or dask.bag. You're in the unhappy situation of having non-uniform columns with too large a file list to play nice with dask.delayed. You could try reading in large batches of files in each delayed call, assuming multiple files can fit into memory, or you could process the entire file list in batches. Alternatively, you could preprocess your data to align it and then read it all in with dd.read_parquet. Good luck!

Comment: I don't think you need the `normalize` function. `dd.concat([dd.read_parquet(path) for path in all_files]).compute()` produces the expected result on my system

Answer (score 1):

`dd.concat` should take care of your normalization.

Consider this example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np

import string

N = 100_000

all_files = []

for col in string.ascii_uppercase[1:]:
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        "A": np.random.normal(size=N),
        col: (np.random.normal(size=N) ** 2) * 50,
    })
    fname = f"df_{col}.parquet"
    all_files.append(fname)
    df.to_parquet(fname)
    
    
full_df = dd.concat([dd.read_parquet(path) for path in all_files]).compute()
```

And I get this on my task stream dashboard:

[image]

Comment: Try this with 10k files. With that I think your innermost [dd.read_parquet(path) for path in all_files] will take forever.

Comment: @rajendra, sure, but if you don't have consistent schemas across your files, you gonna have to make up for that some how.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that was not mentioned in the comments by @Michael Delgado is to load each parquet into a separate `dask` dataframe and then stitch them together. Here's the rough pseudocode:

```py
def normal_ddf(path):
    df = dd.read_parquet(path)
    return normalize(df) # normalize f should work with both pandas and dask

full_df = dd.concat([normal_ddf(path) for path in all_files])
```

Comment: Problem with this is that, when all_files contains large number of files (10K) this takes a long time, since all those dd.read_parquet happens sequentially. Although dd.read_parquet doesn't need to load the whole file, it still needs to read some headers to get column info. Doing it sequentially on 10k files adds up.

Comment: This sounds like a useful piece of information to add to your question...

Comment: @rajendra `dd.read_parquet` is not happening sequentially, but in parallel. You can use `full_df.visualize()` to see the task graph. This is also demonstrated in the image of the task stream in Paul H's answer below.

Comment: @scj13 I think the actual reading of the files happens in parallel, sure. And dd.read_parquet is lazy, it doesn't immediately read the whole file. However, it does a lazy read immediately to get basic info like the columns. And, this lazy read must happen sequentially; given the expression ([normal_ddf(path) for path in all_files]), it's simply impossible that dd.read_parquet won't be called sequentially. 

This lazy reading, while super fast, still adds up.